# How to invoke public static method for existing Java class instance from Scala?

Tags: java, scala, oop, static

Despite there is lot of similar questions around this topic I cannot find any appropriate. This is about commonly used builder + entity approach such as Apache commons CLI `OptionBuilder` + `Option` and corresponding client code migration to Scala.

Illustration in code:

Java classes:

```
public class Entity {

    private int f1;
    private int f2;

    public Entity(int f1, int f2) {
        this.f1 = f1;
        this.f2 = f2;
    }
}

public class Builder {

    private static int f1 = 0;
    private static int f2 = 0;

    private static Builder instance = new Builder();

    static Builder hasF1(int f1) {
        Builder.f1 = f1;
        return Builder.instance;
    }

    static Builder hasF2(int f2) {
        Builder.f2 = f2;
        return Builder.instance;
    }

    static Entity create() {
        return new Entity(Builder.f1, Builder.f2);
    }

}
```

Normal Java code using this approach:

```
Entity entity = Builder.hasF1(5).hasF2(10).create();
```

If this is 'fed' into `scalac` it complains about `Builder` not having `hasF2` field. The point as from my investigation is Scala has no problem to locate `Builder.hasF1` method as `class level one` but after this it needs to call static hasF2 for existing Java class istance and it has problems.

Any idea how this should be properly resolved?

UPDATE:
Related question illustrating all mechanics: [Scala error compiling OptionBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4903296/scala-error-compiling-optionbuilder)

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/4903296/1296806 where I just commented that OptionBuilder is deprecated on trunk.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot do it. You cannot call static methods on instances in Scala. And, in fact, it is considered a bad practice in Java as well, but if that's the interface you have, there's really nothing you can do about it short of building a complete Scala wrapper.

Now, if that code is under *your* control, then all I can say is: don't do that. And, if you don't trust me, go see what Joshua Bloch has to say about it in Effective Java.

Comment: Daniel, thank you for final point in my investigation. It's not under my control. Actually while preparing this question I finally found solution for my case and your point is maybe answer for a general one. :-)

Answer (score 1):

OK, in this case finally came to the following Scala solution:

```
Builder.hasF1(5)
Builder.hasF2(10)
Entity entiry = Builder.create()
```

Which clearly identifies original external library has bad design. My luck it is called at the start of application but I'm considering refactoring such cases in favor of direct `Entity` constructor calls because of potential side effects.

Answer (score 0):

```
static Builder hasF1(int f1) {
    Builder.f1 = f1;
}
```

Does not return anything.

Because `Builder.hasF1(5)` returns nothing, obviously Scala can't find `hasF2`.

Modify hasF1:

```
static Builder hasF1(int f1) {
    Builder.f1 = f1;
    return Builder;
}
```

And do the same for others.