# It is not possible to call static methods of Java classes continuously in scala

Tags: scala

class：org.apache.commons.cli.OptionBuilder

jar:commons-cli-1.2.jar

jdk: 1.8

In Java:

```
OptionBuilder.withArgName("abc").withDescription("bcd");
```

Compiled successfully

The same code in Scala:

```
OptionBuilder.withArgName("abc").withDescription("bcd")
```

Error:(7, 38) value withDescription is not a member of org.apache.commons.cli.OptionBuilder
    OptionBuilder.withArgName("abc").withDescription("bcd")

Comment: Can you share the complete code snippet

Comment: hello， the complete code snippet is downstairs

Comment: So did that work for you?

Comment: not work, the scala code cannot compile

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4903296/scala-error-compiling-optionbuilder

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, You will have to use it as :

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
      OptionBuilder.withArgName("abc")
      OptionBuilder.withDescription("bcd")
    }
```

This is because there is no instance method withDescription in OptionBuilder, only a static method. Since withDescription is a static method, you obviously need to call it on the class, not on an instance of the class.

```
private static OptionBuilder instance = new OptionBuilder();
public static OptionBuilder withArgName(String name)
    {
        OptionBuilder.argName = name;

        return instance;
    }



 public static OptionBuilder withDescription(String newDescription)
    {
        OptionBuilder.description = newDescription;

        return instance;
    }
```

Comment: yes, I was curious why scala can not be called that way

Comment: As far as I know in Java, static methods can be called on an instance, and if there is no corresponding instance method, instead of throwing an error, java will converts it into a static method call for us.

Comment: My god, what a horrible API.